# Delete elements from an input array

Tags: arrays, c

The question is how to delete elements whichs their values equal to an integer x.

In c++, i'm using reference and it works ok, but then when i changed to C, it can't release output.

Here is my code.

Please let me know what I'm wrong, thank you guys !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void Input_array(int a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}
void Output_array(int a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
int find_pos(int a[], int n, int x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == x)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
void delete_pos(int a[], int *n, int pos)
{
    
    int cnt=0;
    for (int i = pos; i < *n - 1; i++)
        //{
        
           
        a[i] = a[i + 1];
        
            
    
    *n=*n-1;
   
}
void delete_elmts(int a[], int *n, int x){
    for(int i=0; i<n;){
        if (a[i]==x)
        {
            delete_pos(a, *n, i);
        }
        else
            i++;
        
    }
}
int main()
{
    
    int n, x;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &x);
    int a[n];
    Input_array(a, n);
    
    delete_elmts(a, &n, x);
    Output_array(a, n);
}
```

Comment: it should be delete_pos(a, n, i)

Comment: *In c++, i'm using reference and it works ok* -- If you did this in C++: `int a[n];`, then you weren't using C++, as that is not legal in C++ unless `n` is a constant.

Comment: No, I mean i'm using `int &n` instead of using `int n`, and well it works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the correct types
2. Use standard functions like memcpy or memmove as they are much more efficient

```
void Input_array(size_t size, int *arr)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = i;
}
void Output_array(size_t size, int *arr)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

size_t delete_pos(const size_t size, const size_t pos, int *arr)
{
    size_t newsize = size;
    if(arr && size && pos < size)
    {
        memmove(arr + pos, arr + pos + 1, sizeof(*arr) * (size - pos));
        newsize--;
    }
    return newsize;
}

size_t delete_elmts(const size_t size, const size_t pos, size_t nelements, int *arr)
{
    if(arr && nelements && pos < size - 1)
    {
        if(pos + nelements > size) nelements = size - pos;
        memmove(arr + pos, arr + pos + nelements, sizeof(*arr) * (size - pos - nelements));
    }
    return size - nelements;
}

#define SIZE 10

int main()
{
    size_t size = SIZE;
    int a[SIZE];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < SIZE + 2; i ++)
    {
        
        Input_array(SIZE, a);
        size = delete_pos(SIZE, i, a);
        Output_array(size, a);
    }
    

    for(size_t i = 0; i < SIZE + 2; i ++)
    {
        for(size_t len = 0; len < SIZE + 1; len++)
        {
            printf("pos = %2zu, len = %2zu:    ", i, len);
            Input_array(SIZE, a);
            size = delete_elmts(SIZE, i, len, a);
            Output_array(size, a);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```